# URLConnection is returning text/html content type

Tags: httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to get the inputstream of online pdf file but the procedure not working. `URLConnection` is returning the `content type` of url as `text/html` instead of `application/pdf`. As you can see `https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao3up7xudju4qm0/Amalgabond%20Adhesive%20Agent.pdf` url is pdf.

I am using the following code for `URLConnection` and getting `Content Type`

```
URL fileUrl;
try {               
String str = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao3up7xudju4qm0/Amalgabond%20Adhesive%20Agent.pdf"
fileUrl = new URL(str);
URLConnection connection = fileUrl.openConnection();
Log.i("mustang", "Content-type: " + connection.getContentType());
InputStream is = fileUrl.openStream();
Log.i("mustang", "is.available(): " + is.available());
```

Due to this, I am unable to parse the buffer. Why I am getting `text/html` content type?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox uses user-agent sniffing to determine if it should display a lightbox (preview of the PDF). What you're seeing is the lightbox code (if you printed the content you would be able to tell this).

You need to add a line specifying a non-interactive user-agent such as wget by adding a line such as:

```
URLConnection connection = fileUrl.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Wget/5.0");
```

This generally overrides dropbox's smart content preview code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I am receiving content type `application/pdf` but `inputstream is.available()` is showing `0` which means `URLConnection` is returning `empty` right?

Comment: Not necessarily, I've seen this sort of behaviour on android, and it doesn't actually mean there's no data - you should try to read so see if the data is being returned.